# neo4j drwho dataset upgrade to 3.0 not working

Tags: neo4j, dataset, upgrade

I am trying to use the "Jim Webber’s Doctor Who Data Set" from http://neo4j.com/developer/example-data/ in my Mac OSX with Neo4j 3.0.1-community.

I am following these steps (doc is [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.0/#upgrading)):

1. download the zip data file into the import directory (for convenience), and rename it as `graph.db`.
2. set `dbms.allow_format_migration=true` in `$NEO4J_HOME/conf/neo4j.conf`
3. Import data using `$NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j-admin import --mode=database --database=graph.db --from=$NEO4J_HOME/import/graph.db/`
4. start neo4j server

The neo4j console doesn't start, with this error message:

```
bin/neo4j console
Starting Neo4j. 
2016-06-15 09:24:11.371+0000 INFO  Starting...
2016-06-15 09:24:12.084+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on localhost:7687.
2016-06-15 09:24:12.296+0000 INFO  Starting upgrade of database
2016-06-15 09:24:12.315+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting  Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@51f07bf0' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@51f07bf0' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@51f07bf0' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:217)
at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:81)
at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:60)
at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:28)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@51f07bf0' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:189)
... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory, /Users/miro/Documents/dev/neo4j/neo4j-community-3.0.1/data/databases/graph.db
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:144)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:40)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.lambda$static$32(CommunityNeoServer.java:55)
at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:89)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@7b464635' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:99)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:140)
... 10 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UnexpectedUpgradingStoreVersionException: '/Users/miro/Documents/dev/neo4j/neo4j-community-3.0.1/data/databases/graph.db/neostore' has a store version 'v0.A.0' that we cannot upgrade from.
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradableDatabase.checkUpgradeable(UpgradableDatabase.java:122)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.migrateIfNeeded(StoreUpgrader.java:129)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.DatabaseMigrator.migrate(DatabaseMigrator.java:98)
at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.upgradeStore(NeoStoreDataSource.java:554)
at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:433)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
... 15 more
```

Does anyeone know how to fix it? Has anyone managed to use the datasets in the doc?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neo4j 3.0 allows direct upgrades from any cleanly shutdown Neo4j 2.x dataset. However the DrWho dataset you're referring to is from old days of Neo4j 1.9 (or even earlier). Due to this you need a two step upgrade process:

1. download Neo4j 2.3.3 (or any new 2.x release)
2. unpack the drwho.zip into `data/graph.db`
3. set `allow_store_upgrade=true` in `conf/neo4j.properties`
4. start the database and stop it gracefully
5. unpack neo4j 3.0.x
6. copy the `data/graph.db` from Neo4j 2.x to `data/databases/graph.db`
7. set `dbms.allow_format_migration=true` in `conf/neo4j.conf`
8. start up Neo4j 3.0.x

Comment: Thank you Stefan. I see that being in version 1, a two step upgrade is needed. I haven't tried this, since I prefered to have a simpler use case. @marcoL also suggested another resource which was pointing to a similar solution. So, I check this is the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Stefan! This is a simple and clear solution!
Furthermore it can be executed programmatically with both 2x and 3x neo4j versions installed.